# Okay to call prompt() this way?

Tags: javascript

Is it okay to call prompt this way:

```
  prompt('Enter your text here');
```

instead of:

```
  prompt('Enter your text here', '');
```

I.e. without passing a suggested input to it?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Yes, it is OK.**

The second parameter to `prompt` method is *optional* (see ["window.prompt on MDN"](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/window.prompt)). 
As according to ECMAScript specification (ECMA-262, section 4.3.9), a value of `undefined` is given to a variable which has no assigned value. In the `prompt` method, it doesn't matter whether you leave the second parameter as `undefined` or pass an empty string to it: both result in empty string as default value in the prompt.

In case you are wondering why this information is not available on DOM standards such as [W3C DOM](http://www.w3.org/DOM/) the answer is that it is a non-standard method that is "just" commonly supported by browsers (part of so called "DOM Level 0" spec). However, the upcoming HTML 5 is likely to define prompt (`window.prompt`) as a standard method (see ["6.4 User prompts"](http://dev.w3.org/html5/spec-author-view/user-prompts.html)).

Comment: See my answer, `prompt` does now appear in a (draft) specification: HTML5, which is about a lot more than just HTML. :-)

Comment: @T.J. Crowder: for completeness I added the remark on HTML 5 to my answer as well. Again thanks for this valuable finding!

Comment: *"...I would encourage you to use method `window.prompt` instead of `prompt`."* `prompt` **is** `window.prompt`, on every browser I can find: http://jsbin.com/idofoh `prompt` is just a global pointing to a function, and all globals are properties of the global object (the window object, on browsers).

Comment: Very good point. I will update my answer accordingly. Thanks!

Comment: Note that I just added an answer because it seems in IE7, not explicitly providing an empty string as the second argument leads to the string 'undefined' being prefilled. :-(

Answer (score 3):

In the [documentation on MDC](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/window.prompt), the second parameter is listed as optional.

> **value** is a string containing the default value displayed in the text input field. *It is an optional parameter*.

Comment: So, what happens when value is not provided? Is it set to `undefined` then? BTW, the resource is awesome.

Comment: @OliverWeiler: No placeholder text will be set.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, the second parameter is optional [according to the HTML5 spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/timers.html#user-prompts) (the closest thing we currently have to a specification of `prompt` and `alert` and such):

> The `prompt(message, default)` method, when invoked, must release the storage mutex, show the given message to the user, and ask the user to either respond with a string value or abort. The user agent must then pause as the method waits for the user's response. **The second argument is optional.** If the second argument (`default`) is present, then the response must be defaulted to the value given by default. If the user aborts, then the method must return `null`; otherwise, the method must return the string that the user responded with.

*(My emphasis)*

Answer (score 3):

I thought the answer was 'yes', until I just saw that in IE7, this will result in having 'undefined' prefilled in the input box instead. Try it out for yourself in IE7 with a quick JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/ALw6r/

Edit: from the comments, seems this is also broken in IE8.

Comment: The same is true for IE8 in fact.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, that is valid JavaScript. As w3schools mentions on http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_prompt.asp it's optional

Comment: W3schools has massive errors in some sections - For JS stuff, I recommend using MDN instead: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/window.prompt

Comment: of course this is correct, but [w3schools isn't really authoritative](http://w3fools.com/).

Comment: Better yet, how 'bout using a specification?

Comment: I wouldn't know which spec to use. `prompt()` isn't in the ECMAscript spec and not in the HTML4.01 spec either. If I'm not mistaken, the only official JavaScript documentation comes from Mozilla, since they are the ones who developed JavaScript. Does that count as a spec though?

Comment: @TomvanderWoerdt: See my answer. This *is* now being standardized. Mozilla officially documents **JavaScript** [their proprietary ECMAScript variant, like JScript is Microsoft's -- but with a lot more gravitas, since they (as Netscape) started it :-) ], not ECMAScript or browser standards. (Instead, they participate in TC-39 of the ECMA and in the HTML5 working group.)